# UserInfo Discord Bot Command. TypeError: Cannot read property 'roles' of null

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

My command: it does what it has to do. I can mention a user or use his id

```js
let args = message.content.split(' ');

if (args.length > 2) return message.channel.send('Only mention one user!');
if (!args[1]) return message.channel.send('Mention someone!');

if (args[1]) {
 let member = message.guild.member(
  message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[1])
 );

 let roles = member.roles.cache
  .filter((r) => r.name !== '@everyone')
  .map((role) => role.name)
  .join('\n');
 if (roles.length === 0) roles = '-';

 if (member) {
  let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
   .setColor(tesseract.Constants.COLORS.TEAL)
   .setTitle('User Info')
   .setThumbnail(member.user.displayAvatarURL())
   .setAuthor(
    `${member.user.tag} (${member.id})`,
    member.user.displayAvatarURL()
   )
   .addField('**Username:**', `${member.user.username}`, true)
   .addField('**Discriminator:**', `${member.user.discriminator}`, true)
   .addField('**ID:**', `${member.user.id}`, true)
   .addField('**Status:**', `${member.user.presence.status}`, true)
   .addField('**Joined On:**', `${member.joinedAt.toLocaleString()}`, true)
   .addField(
    '**Created On:**',
    `${member.user.createdAt.toLocaleString()}`,
    true
   )
   .setDescription(roles)
   .setFooter(
    `© ${message.guild.me.displayName}`,
    this.client.user.displayAvatarURL()
   );

  message.channel.send(embed);
 } else {
  message.channel.send(`Could not find that member`);
 }
}
```

Now i want to add that i can search for a user outside the discord. (Bot is added to 2 discords) So i want to do the user command on the second discord and search for a user from the first discord. i get this done with `client.users.cache.get('user id')` but due to the roles function i get a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'roles' of null`. If i remove the role funcion it works fine..
How can I ignore the role function when its searching for `client.users.cache.get('user id')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is telling you that `member` is `null`. This happens when `args[1]` is not a valid ID or the user is not in the guild.

Check that a valid member was supplied before getting the member's roles:

```js
// You don't need to wrap this in a message.guild.member()
let member = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[1]);
if (member) {
  let roles = member.roles.cache
    .filter((r) => r.name !== '@everyone')
    .map((role) => role.name)
    .join('\n');
  // rest of code...
}
```